# how solve ContactUI with iOS16 no cancel and done buttons

Tags: swift, swiftui, contactsui

I have a little trouble with the ContactsUI in my app. With iOS 16 when I want add a contact there are not the cancel and done button. Have someone an idea how to solve it ?
I have attached code and screen

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import ContactsUI

struct EditInternalContactView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  typealias UIViewControllerType = CNContactViewController
  var contact: Binding<CNContact>
  var presentingEditContact: Binding<Bool>

  func makeCoordinator() -> EditInternalContactView.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EditInternalContactView>) -> Self.UIViewControllerType {
    let controller = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact.wrappedValue)
    controller.delegate = context.coordinator
    return controller
  }

  func updateUIViewController(
    _ uiViewController: EditInternalContactView.UIViewControllerType,
    context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<EditInternalContactView>) {}
}

extension EditInternalContactView {
  final class Coordinator: NSObject, CNContactViewControllerDelegate {
    var parent: EditInternalContactView

    init(_ contactDetail: EditInternalContactView) {
      self.parent = contactDetail
    }

    func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
      parent.contact.wrappedValue = contact ?? parent.contact.wrappedValue
      parent.presentingEditContact.wrappedValue = false
    }

    func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, so I post the answer for all the one who has the same problem.

The problem was that the controller must be into a UINavigationController and you expose the navigation Controller.

Here the code:

```
import Foundation
import ContactsUI
import SwiftUI

struct ContactView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  var isPresenting: Binding<Bool>
  var contact: CNContact?

  func makeCoordinator() -> ContactView.Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
  }

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContactView>) -> UIViewController {
    let contactViewController = makeContactViewController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: contactViewController)
    contactViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    return navigationController
  }

  func updateUIViewController(
    _ uiViewController: UIViewController,
    context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ContactView>) {}

  private var makeContactViewController: CNContactViewController {
    if let contact = self.contact {
      let viewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
      viewController.title = nil
      return viewController
    } else {
      return CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contact)
    }
  }
}

extension ContactView {
  final class Coordinator: NSObject, CNContactViewControllerDelegate {
    var parent: ContactView

    init(_ contactView: ContactView) {
      self.parent = contactView
    }

    func contactViewController(
      _ viewController: CNContactViewController,
      didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?
    ) {
      parent.isPresenting.wrappedValue = false
    }

    func contactViewController(
      _ viewController: CNContactViewController,
      shouldPerformDefaultActionFor property: CNContactProperty
    ) -> Bool {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```